# Read scroll only from a specific block

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is necessary that the scroll was read precisely in the "second" block, and not from the beginning of the document, and when, in the end, the posts are loaded via ajax, it will go quietly to the third block. In short, actions need to take place only in the "second" block.

```css
  jQuery(window).on('scroll', onScroll); 
        function onScroll(){ 
          if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() +    100   + jQuery(window).height()   > jQuery(document).height()) {
          //ajax
          }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div> 
    <div class="second">
        <div class="post"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="third"></div>
```

I tried so `jQuery('.second').on('scroll', onScroll);` but does not work. If so `jQuery(window).on('scroll', onScroll);`  then everything works, but if replaced with a class or id, it doesn’t work

Comment: Is the ajax same for every block?

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwari Yes, ajax only works in the `second` block and by default there are already three posts. That’s not the point, it’s even on those blocks on which there is no ajax, for some reason it doesn’t see a scroll, because if I write even like that `jQuery('.first').on('scroll', o` he will not work. that's when it says `window`  then everything works great, but I would like it to read the scroll in a certain block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for your element's offset to see at what point you have scrolled. Also assigning an ajax call to scroll listener is not a very good idea if you don't want too many ajax requests. So if you want to limit the call to one, then you should maintain a state.

```js
var second = document.getElementById('.second'); // selector to your element
var state = false; // To store the state whether the ajax call has been already made

jQuery(window).on('scroll', onScroll); 
function onScroll(){ 
          if (window.scrollY > second.offsetTop && !state) {
          //ajax
          ...
          ...
          state = true; //So that it does not enter this block again
          }
}
```

The above solution works if there is one such block, but if you have multiple like these, then something like this could be used.

You can ignore the `loadedSelectors` if you don't want to limit the ajax call to once, but not limiting will be a bad idea for your call stack.

```js
var selectors = ['second' , 'third' , 'fourth']; //All the selectors you want to have a scroll listener
var loadedSelectors = []; //Here we can add all the blocks that are already added

jQuery(window).on('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll(){ 
selectors.forEach(function(i)){
   if (window.scrollY > document.getElementByClassName(i).offsetTop && loadedSelectors.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
          //ajax
          ...
          ...
          loadedSelectors.push(i); // Adding to the loaded list of blocks
        }
}
```